# Do kotlin have Android framework?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, frameworks

I don't want waste my time learning java, I want to go straight and learn kotlin but it seems to me that kotlin do not have Android framework like java do,so am just confused about it because I like kotlin.so what am I going to do, you all know that it very effective if you just focus on one task at a time.

Comment: I mean, did you even try searching "kotlin android" on a search engine before asking? https://developer.android.com/kotlin

Comment: You should deserve a downvote only because of what you said. Learning Java is NEVER a waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin doesn't have the Android framework, neither does JAVA.

The Android API was built using the JAVA API. This means the classes and methods contained in the JAVA language are used to create the classes and methods for Android.

Android applications compile and run on a modified Java virtual machine, this is why.

Kotlin is compatible with Java, what this means, is that the code written in Kotlin is then transpile to Java, and that is what ends up running (as explained above).

The reason why Kotlin has become popular for writing Android applications is that meet the requirements of modern applications better. Java was born in an imperative programming paradigm, yet most modern applications leverage functional programming for handling the complexity.

Kotlin combines functional and imperative programming, making it better to work on Android.

Google has publicly announced that Kotlin is the official Android language, which makes the support for Kotlin something that comes from the source it self.